# How get specific columns of table and its foreign key as object using Java Hibernate and Criteria

Tags: java, spring, performance, hibernate, criteria

Suppose I have an object User (with several properties) mapped in java spring using hibernate and the object Adress (also with several properties) where in the `hbm.xml` file of User there is a many-to-one relationship with Address.

```
public class User{
     Long id;
     String name;
     Integer age;
     Address address;
}

public class Address{
     Long id;
     String description;
     Integer number;
     String state;
     String country;
}
```

I want to make a query using criteria where I want to get ONLY the `id, name` of User and ONLY `id, description, number` of the Addres.

I already tried using `setProjection` but if put `id,name,address` in the projection list it will get all properties from Address, but I only want some specific for performance issues.

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(User.class, "user");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("user.id"),"id")
            .add(Projections.property("user.name"),"name")                
            .add(Projections.property("user.address"),"address")
    ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

I'm using a older version of hibernate so it is using xml file to map the java object and the database table:

```
    <class name="com.models.impl.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" column="USER_ID"></id>
        ...
        <many-to-one lazy="false" name="address" class="com.models.impl.Address" >
              <column name="ADDR_ID"/>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
```

In this case, making a second query filtering the Address (and its specific columns) by the user id is not a option to me. With that I would have to open another connection with the database and since I have a query with more than three thousand rows the performance cost of two queries would be very high.

Anyone could help me out?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using? You will have to join the address association to project only specific fields/columns, something like this maybe:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(User.class, "user");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("user.id"),"id")
        .add(Projections.property("user.name"),"name")                
        .add(Projections.property("user.address.number"),"addressNumber")                
        .add(Projections.property("user.address.state"),"addressState")
).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
```

I don't know the exact details of the legacy Hibernate Criteria API, but I think with this information you should be able to figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christian. I tried this solution but there was an error saying that could not find the property `user.addres.number`. Apparently the projection doesn't recognize inner associations.

Comment: Then you will have to do some kind of join (I don't know much about the legacy Hibernate Criteria API) or use the JPA Criteria API which supports this.